# Using Turbo Memory in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, readyboost, turbo-boost

as some of you already know Turbo memory is no longer supported for Windows 10. I tried today installing Intel's driver to my OS, 1.10.1.1002. It seems to work and I rebooted the system but the readyboost or the readydrive are not turned on intel turbo memory console. I tried checking them again and reboot, same result. I also try checking them and refresh, the tick was removed afterward. I guess Windows 10 do not have the interface like its predecessor so the console cannot see the services required.

Now, I want to be able to just read the turbo memory as a hard disk, but I failed to find it in my disk manager, and also didn't seem to find a driver that can just turn it into disk. Once I can do it, I can manually turn on readyboost from disk properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First run command prompt as admin.

Run `diskpart`

Then:

`list disk`

Select the one that is your turbo memory, usually the first one disk 0.

`select disk 0`

Then you need to clean the disk and create a partition.

> clean
>
> create partition primary
>
> active
>
> select part 1

Then you will need to format it. NOTE, only FAT format works.

`format fs=fat quick`

Done.